# Assigning member group at same time as activating Pending member

Tags: ee2, control-panel, members

I have a site in which each member group has (of course) a different set of viewing and posting privileges. It is also set up to place new membership requests into Pending, until manually activated by the site admin -- at which time the applicant receives an email informing them that their account is active, and the member's account moves from Pending to the default group, Member_group_X. All this is, of course, completely normal EE out-of-the-box behaviour.

What I have not found, either natively or via an add-on, is a way to assign a new account to a different (non-default) member group *at the time that it is manually activated by the admin*. Not having this ability risks letting the newly-activated member log-in before the admin has had a chance to move them to the correct member group, thereby exposing information that should be hidden.

Does anyone have a way of combining the 'Activate Pending members' process with the 'moving a member to a different group' process?

Answer (score 5):

I'm pretty sure that the [Solspace User Module](http://www.solspace.com/software/detail/user/) allows you to assign a specific 'on activation' member group for new registrations created through the modules front end tags. When approved the user is then automatically moved to the relevant group.

Comment: Nathan; I'm already using User and it is very helpful for most of the membership application process, so thanks for the suggestion -- it’s a good one. Thing is, I don't want the applicant to be choosing which group they'll end up in; that's a decisions for the site admin, so can't really be implemented at the front end.

Comment: Ok. If the problem is the danger that they could be approved and put in the wrong member group in error why not make the default group assignment a group with no privs (a holding cell if you like). Your admins can then manually move users form this to the relevant group. If you turn off email notification of account approval (or change the message) admins could then contact members directly to let them know when they have been assigned to the right member group and are able to log-in.

Comment: I know that's not 'exactly' the answer but it might be a halfway house solution. :)

Comment: Nathan. Yes, that is an option. In fact I've simply made the default group that one with the least 'security issues' — members might be temporarily able to post to certain channels that they wouldn't otherwise have posting access to, but that's less problematic than exposing sensitive pricing information. The only reason that I don't fancy your 'holding cell' idea, valid though it is, is that these members will have already received an email saying “Your account application is being manually reviewed and you'll be notified when it is activated”; stalling them *again* could be irritating.

Answer (score 3):

You can always edit the member directly, click on Member Preferences in the left hand menu and change them from Pending to whatever member group they should belong to. (Instead of following the usual Activate Members admin routine.)

Comment: I didn't know that, Richard, thanks. (I mean, I knew about changing member groups via Member Preferences but I didn't realise that simply moving them out of Pending would also activate the account).

Comment: I haven't tested this, but one possible downside to Richard’s suggestion occurred to me: moving a member out of the Pending group via Member Preferences presumably would NOT send out the automatic email that gets sent when it’s done via 'Activate Pending Members'. Am I right about that?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, your only hope here was the [cp_members_validate_members](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/development/extension_hooks/cp/members/index.html#cp-members-validate-members) extension hook. But alas, it gives you no access to the information you might need about which members were just validated.